# Is it possible to restore songs from an iPod to iTunes?

Tags: data-recovery, ipod-classic

I have a 160 GB iPod Classic and a Windows 7 desktop with iTunes containing roughly about 13,000 songs. My external hard drive containing all the songs crashed but I managed as long as all the songs' file names were in iTunes and when the iPod syncronised with iTunes, the songs remained on the iPod. Recently I had my computer reinstalled and iTunes was formatted and wiped clean, now if I sync my iPod I know my iPod will be wiped clean as well.

So is it possible to recover songs which are there — on the iPod — but not in iTunes or the desktop?

Answer (score 1):

There is no end to the people that will offer to sell you some software to do this.

Here is a long list:
https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3991

There should be several free ways to do this including this one:
http://download.cnet.com/PhoneTrans/3000-18553_4-75736709.html

Many advertising free downloads but are crippled and will only allow a few songs at a time.

I don't use windows so I cannot recommend one or the other but I would not pay for something you can find for free if you just look a little bit.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to transfer you audio/video files from your iPod to your Desktop. If you follow [this guide](http://www.freedvdripper.net/how-to-transfer-music-from-ipod-to-another-ipod.html) you should be fine.

> **Step 1:** Download and install  [iPod to computer transfer](http://www.reviewstown.com/ipod-to-computer/ipod-iphone-to-computer-transfer-cucusoft.html). Your iPod should be detected automatically.
>
> **Step 2:** Choose the list and files you want to transfer, click the Start Transfer button.
>
> **Step 3:** After clicking the Start Transfer button, a window will pop up. You can choose, whether you want to transfer your audio/video files directly to iTunes or to a folder on your disk. *(If you want the files transferred to a folder, make sure you set it in Settings before starting the transfer)*

Hope this helps...Good luck!